# My JSON isn't being decoded by PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

My PHP script is having a problem decoding the JSON that I'm sending to it via AJAX.

The jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'admin/modifyPermissions',
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        'JSON' : JSON
    },
    success : function(msg){
        if(msg == '1') {
            alert('Permissions saved successfully');
        } else {
            alert(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

The PHP script:

```
public function modifyPermissions(){

    if(isset($_POST['JSON']) && !empty($_POST['JSON'])) {
        $json = json_decode($_POST['JSON'],true);
        if($json !== NULL && $json !== FALSE) {

        } elseif($json === NULL){
            die('The string passed is not a valid JSON object and cannot be decoded.' . "\n" . $_POST['JSON']);
        } else {
            die('There was an error with the JSON string');
        }
    } else {
        die('No JSON string was sent!');
    }
}
```

The JSON that gets passed looks well formed to me:

```
{"martin":{3,5},"user2":{3,4,5}}
```

And PHP is returning null. I have PHP 5.2.7 installed on my server, so I can't use json_last_error()

Comment: Your JSON should be `{"martin":[3,5],"user2":[3,4,5]}` Note the use of `[` and `]` for ordered sets over `{` and `}`

Comment: It doesn't matter that the JSON looks well-formed to you, because it's not. When in doubt, use a JSON validator to check: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{"martin":{3,5},"user2":{3,4,5}}
```

Not valid JSON. Valid JSON may look like this:

```
{"martin":[3,5],"user2":[3,4,5]}
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending valid JSON, thus the error. Look at the comment @Matt added.

So that you won't reproduce the same error, before sending it over to PHP, don't try to make your own JSON string, use what JS offers you. Example:

```
var obj = { key: val, okey: oval }
objJSON = JSON.stringify(obj)
// objJSON is ALWAYS going to be valid json
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid.

The `{}` notation denotes key/value pairs, where as you're using it as an array.

Your JSON should be,

```
{"martin":[3,5],"user2":[3,4,5]}
```